# Adding a watermark to a GIF with reasonable quality using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

so I got this code to add a logo onto a folder full of GIFs

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%G in ("%~dp0webm\*.gif") do (
    ffmpeg -i %%G -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=trunc(iw/5):trunc(ih/16)[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-4 [v]" -map "[v]" "C:\Users\Propietario\Desktop\Conversion\gif\%%~nG.gif"
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

However, the output quality is rather low, similar to an issue I had with converting from video to GIF which was solved by creating a palette.

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -filter_complex palettegen[PAL];[0:v]fifo[v0];[v0][PAL]paletteuse output.gif
```

Issue is, both solutions use `-filter_complex` so I don't know exactly how to combine the two in a way in which I'll be able to turn GIFs into watermarked GIFs with reasonable quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add watermark to GIF without quality loss.

GIF have upto 256 color and must be treated as pixel art, not smooth images as video. Tools for video processing expected video as sequence of smooth images. Somewhere here conversion between world of crisp pixels and world of smooth images, which CAN NOT BE done without loss. GIF also uses many tricks, like very adaptive palette, for example, so if you want add white logo, here may be no white color in palette. And here no "alpha blending" any attempt to combine colors will change palette map dramatically, all image will be distorted.

If you really want add overlay, if theory, you can unpack pixels as PALETTE IMAGE (video processing tools in our time can't do it), analyze watermark, adapt watermark for current palette (yes, you must change your watermark, if you don't want change image), add watermark to image and repack image again. This is complex task and I don't know tools for it. As internet user, I don't support practice, when good content labeled by someone with unneeded watermarks, I prefer originals, so I don't like to write such software.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I guess I may have to accept that quality loss in the gifs, and I agree completely with you but I had so much of my content shamelessly stolen that I'd like to start putting at least a tiny watermark in a corner to discourage them from it.

Comment: Do not lie to us, if it was really your content, you could add a watermark at the production stage, as many artists do. You are another site that takes someone else's work and molds your name on it. Each post is a repost of a repost of stolen repost.

Comment: Granted that the content on itself isn't mine but the editing done to it is content in of itself (at least in my opinion), I really don't like seeing it on other pages with that one black bar on top adding text to it.

Comment: @bukkojot ffmpeg has filters to analyze GIF and produce a custom global palette including a per-frame palette with adaptive transparency, and then encode GIF using those palettes.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%G in ("%~dp0webm\*.gif") do (
    ffmpeg -i %%G -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=trunc(iw/5):trunc(ih/16)[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-4,palettegen [v]" -map "[v]" "C:\Users\Propietario\Desktop\Conversion\gif\%%~nG-palette.png"
    ffmpeg -i %%G -i watermark.png -i "%%~nG-palette.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=trunc(iw/5):trunc(ih/16)[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-4[ov];[ov][2]paletteuse [v]" -map "[v]" "C:\Users\Propietario\Desktop\Conversion\gif\%%~nG.gif"
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: The quality is still bad, there's some lines all across the GIF similar to the examples on this website I found on another thread http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html, I can't seem to get rid of them even with 'paletteuse'

Comment: Wait, it seems I wasn't implementing it right, I fixed that to be in line with what you posted, my console crashes while creating the palette for some reason.

Comment: @NeoHerakles Try it unscripted and run it manually in cmd. Does it still crash? If yes, please show the complete console output. If you are unfamiliar with copying from the console use the `-report` option to output an excessively verbose log file (it will appear in current directory).

Comment: It's alright, I tried an alternative solution, thanks a lot.